# How can I correctly interpret the results of logistic regression?

Tags: logistic

I built the logistic regression model and the results have good accuracy, but I have a question.

Let's say the predicted probability value is 0.86. And the total accuracy in the classification matrix of the model was 94%.
How  can I correctly interprete this?

Can I say that with a 94% accuracy the probability of an event is 0.86? 
If not, how can I correctly describe it?

Answer (score 8):

Completely ignore the classification table.  The purpose of logistic regression is to estimate probabilities of events.  You can interpret the predictive discrimination of the model using for example the $c$-index (concordance probability; area under the ROC curve).  Also consider a calibration curve.  Much has been written about these on stackexchange.  Concordance is the probability that, of a randomly chosen pair of observations, one with and one without the event, the one with the event has the higher predicted probability of the event.

Comment: Thanx, Frank. Area under the ROC curve was=0.95. So how interprete this fact?

Comment: 0.95 'is the probability that, of a randomly chosen pair of observations, one with and one without the event, the one with the event has the higher predicted probability of the event.'

Comment: so , did i right understand, if AUC=0,32, it is the probability that, of a randomly chosen pair of observations, one with and one without the event, the one without the event has the higher predicted probability that the event will not occur?

Comment: Yes i.e. predictions are worse than random if the overall proportion is less than 0.5

Comment: The last question. Can i don't consider the probability low than 0.7?
For example, I have an observation of the class "0", but  model predicted a probability of 0.62 (arithmetically rounded - to 1 ). There is also 0.76 probability of obs., which is belong to "0" class (here I think that it was wrong classification). I believe that the prop. less than 0.7 can't be consider as probability of event. Tell me, am I right or not?

Comment: I recently wrote a short article on why the AUC has the interpretation that Frank refers to here: http://madrury.github.io/jekyll/update/statistics/2017/06/21/auc-proof.html

Comment: @psysky I can't follow the logic of why you would consider some probabilities not probabilities.  The probs. stand in their own right; we're just talking about pairs because that's all the $c$-index uses.

Comment: I calculated spec and sens.
How on the basis of these values do I manually calculate the AUC? spec=0,06,sens=0.94

Comment: You can't compute concordance probability from just those 2 numbers.  It is esssential the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney statistic for comparing predicted risks for $Y=0$ and $Y=1$ groups.

Comment: So, i have to compare @predicted values@ using U-test. Ok here the result, what conclusion can i do?   [screen](http://fastpic.co/image/PlRamI)

Comment: No you don't have to do that; I was just pointing out an equivalence.  The gold standard for what you want is the logistic model likelihood ratio chi-square test with degrees of freedom equal to the number of opportunities (candidate variables, for example) you had to find associations between $X$s and $Y$.